# How to pass variable within javascript to onclick HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Good Evening, I am doing a function which going to pass the number of pages into a javascript but I dunno how to pass it back into an onclick html checkbox. The display function is getting the same pageNum as the displayAtCheckBox function, I try to call with the code provided but it always jump to first page when I click the checkbox.

> Sample Code

```
<script>
function display(pageNum){
//do something
}

function displayAtCheckBox(pageNum){
//do something
}
</script>

<td><A HREF='' onclick="display(1)">1</A></td>
<td><A HREF='' onclick="display(2)">2</A></td>
<td><A HREF='' onclick="display(3)">3</A></td>
<td><A HREF='' onclick="display(4)">4</A></td>
```

> How can I display the same pageNum contents?Example: when I click 4, then click the checkbox. It will displayAtCheckBox(4).

```
<INPUT type=checkbox onclick='***displayAtCheckBox(1)***'>
```

No url is involved because of security reason. Need some hints and advised, thanks in advanced^^

Comment: call `displayAtCheckBox(pageNum)` in you function `display(pageNum)` in the end may be;

Comment: erm, can any1 tell me why my reputation being deducted?
Is it my question is unclear or is it the original question dont have <script>//= =</script>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your anchors :

```
<a href="" onclick="display(x); return false;">x</a>
```

Comment: erm, dont understand why you do like that?

Comment: When using `return false;` the browser won't execute the default event for the anchor which is redirecting to the url

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false in the onclick events of your anchors:

```
<a href="" onclick="display(n);return false;">n</a>
```

Then, you could easily implement a mechanic in `display` to save the last displayed number.

```
var currentPageNum = theOneDisplayed;

function display(pageNum) {
    // ...

    currentPageNum = pageNum;
}

function displayAtCurrentCheckBox() {
    // ...
    displayAtCheckBox(currentPageNum);
}
```

And you can simplify your checkbox to:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="displayAtCurrentCheckBox()" />
```

Comment: where are you calling `display()` ?

Comment: just before returning false (see DarkBee's explanation on it)